# PS script one liner issue

Tags: powershell

I have this one liner which works in PowerShell.

```
If (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {} Else {$RegistryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\"; $NewRegKey = "SCCM"; New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Name $NewRegKey -Force; $NewRegKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM"; $KeyName = "W10_IPU_Attempts"; $Value = "0"; New-ItemProperty -Path $NewRegKeyPath -Name $KeyName -Value $Value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null}; $i= $Value =(Get-Itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM').W10_IPU_Attempts; If ($i -eq $value){ $i++; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -Name W10_IPU_Attempts -Value $i } else { $i++; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -Name W10_IPU_Attempts -Value $i }
```

Now when I add the following and testing it I get errors in smsts.log that it's incorrect function. When running via CMD I get "The string is missing the terminator" `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command " & If (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {} Else {$RegistryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\"; $NewRegKey = "SCCM"; New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Name $NewRegKey -Force; $NewRegKeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM"; $KeyName = "W10_IPU_Attempts"; $Value = "0"; New-ItemProperty -Path $NewRegKeyPath -Name $KeyName -Value $Value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null}; $i= $Value =(Get-Itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM').W10_IPU_Attempts; If ($i -eq $value){ $i++; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -Name W10_IPU_Attempts -Value $i } else { $i++; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -Name W10_IPU_Attempts -Value $i }"`

I can't find where I am missing to complete this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove the ampersand before the `IF` -> `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command " &`

Comment: that is not really what is meant by a one-liner since every semi-colon is a stand-in for a linefeed. [*grin*] ///// however, the usual source of the error you report is an invalid character [em-dash instead of dash OR typographic quotes instead of vertical quotes]. try opening your code in the ISE to see what gets marked with red squiggles.

Comment: We don't you move your "one"-liner to ps1 file`

Comment: ps1 works but then you'll need to package it. If I can't get this one liner to work then yeah...I suppose I could package it with the .ps1

Comment: Anything this long needs to be a script. The reason you are having issues, is that you are apparently doing this in the consolehost and not in one of the PowerShell editors (ISE/VSCode) that would highlight errors in your code and show you matching parens, braces.. As noted by Lee, this is not a one-liner. It's a script all put on one line. Which makes it inordinately hard to read, follow, troubleshoot, and share with others. Remember, be a good citizen that think about those who will follow you when you move up or on in your career. Do, you actually expect someone to type this out each time.

Comment: Why the need of smashing everything into one line of code? That way, you are almost sure to get it wrong, because mistakes are easily overlooked as it is in this case. Also, whenever you need to change something in that code, you will probably end up making the same mistakes again and again. Write larger code in neatly indentented separate lines!

Comment: Theo, there are many reasons to use one liner. Regardless, I have resolved my own question and shared my answer anyway. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Came to realized how important it is to be consistent. I am able to fix the problem because I fixed all of my quotations. For anyone interested, this is the final script.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "If (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {} Else {$RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\'; $NewRegKey = 'SCCM'; New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Name $NewRegKey -Force; $NewRegKeyPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM'; $KeyName = 'W10_IPU_Attempts'; $Value = '0'; New-ItemProperty -Path $NewRegKeyPath -Name $KeyName -Value $Value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null}; $i= $Value =(Get-Itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM').W10_IPU_Attempts; If ($i -eq $value){ $i++; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -Name W10_IPU_Attempts -Value $i } else { $i++; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -Name W10_IPU_Attempts -Value $i }"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is full script, not a one-liner. Why not deliver it as a well formatted script, so that these sort of things can be easily / visually caught. The moment I put you post in an editor, all the mistakes were obvious.

Example refactor:

```
If (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
{
    # Do nothing
}
Else 
{
    $RegistryPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\'
    $NewRegKey = 'SCCM'

    New-Item -Path $RegistryPath -Name $NewRegKey -Force

    $NewRegKeyPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM'
    $KeyName = 'W10_IPU_Attempts'
    $Value = '0'

    $newItemPropertySplat = @{
        Path = $NewRegKeyPath
        PropertyType = 'DWORD'
        Name = $KeyName
        Force = $true
        Value = $Value
    }
    New-ItemProperty @newItemPropertySplat | 
    Out-Null
}

$i = $Value = (Get-Itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM').W10_IPU_Attempts

If ($i -eq $value)
{ 
    $i++
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -Name W10_IPU_Attempts -Value $i 
} 
else 
{ 
    $i++
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SCCM' -Name W10_IPU_Attempts -Value $i 
}
```

Comment: That is my original script if I were to package it. Unfortunately, I am looking for a one line execution. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Then keep it as a script for all who follow you, but package it as a .exe using say PS2EXE ... https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5 --- for someone to just double click to run? This way, one can always come back to troubleshoot it properly, but the user does not need to strain themselves trying to read a 700+ char string. Just say'in… ;-}

Comment: I think you misread because I wanted to keep all in one line. Thanks and have a great day. Solution has been found.

Comment: I get that. So, not a misread, but we all have to make choices that fit whatever use case is needed. So, whatever works. and ditto.